# Rolling picture box

Tags: javascript, banner

The first part of the following question was solved by
Andrew Danylchenko - www.zebrasus.com
Thanks a ton for taking a look

If anyone knows why Firefox is reporting a sporadic issue with "div-animation.js" that would still be helpful.

---

I created most of this JavaScript code myself. Everything was working fine until a few days ago. Im not sure what I changed but now my code no longer works in FF but works fine in IE?

Can you please take a look at
http://webstudioproductions.com/demo/TPR/test.html

and let me know what I did wrong in homepageScroll.js.

It looks like the function is trying to fire but something is stopping it.

Side note: FF is reporting a sporadic JS issue in div-animation.js but its functioning as designed cross all browsers?

Comment: I am actively working this issue with some other javascript experts. Thank you all for this help!

Comment: It looks like chrome is failing to download some of the images on the page. You might want to check your image URLs.

Comment: it works fine in chrome. altho, the images aren't loading (404 error)

Comment: Its ok, the major issue was resolved. The problem now just lies in the bottom collapsing divs and why FF is sometime reporting issues with running the script. Also, Im trying to think of a way to run the script without relying on the script to format the links after page load. As it stands now there is a 2 sec delay from page load to script run formatting and ppl see the page blink for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the collapsing divs as I"m seeing nothing but a facebook like button in the latest build of Chrome on Mac OSX. The html file appears to be linking to the js files you mention.

Inside the js files there's nothing I can see that's "wrong". However, try using literal notation when declaring your arrays, so

```
var foo = new Array();
```

becomes

```
var foo = [];
```

Also, some problems may be occurring if the time set on your setTimout declarations falls below 10. Many browsers throttle the time at 10ms (even if you explicitly specify '0'), so putting a condition somewhere to make sure that the number never falls below 10 could help.